# SSL website (subdirectory none SSL)

Tags: ssl

We have built a website (wordpress / hosting2go.nl) with SSL (https) with a subdomain.

- Website: https://www.oso-wonen.nl
- Subdomain: http://bestuur.oso-wonen.nl

We need this subdomain for our agenda and minutes protected with a
password.

We do voluntary work for elderly people with a housing problem, so we have no money to purchase a supper SSL certificate.

Who knows a solution to still get https on this sundomain.

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Eh? Let's Encrypt is free.

Comment: You need a Wild Card SSL Certificate to protect the main domain and any additional sub domains. These aren't usually cheap. Maybe Let's Encrypt allows this?

Comment: @suchislife why would you need a wildcard certificate? I only see two names here, "www.oso-wonen.nl" and "bestuur.oso-wonen.nl".

Comment: Just issue a new (freE) Let's Encrypt certficate for the domain ... it's even autoconfiguring your vhosts.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is to provide free SSL certificates for everyone (as in, "everyone who actually owns the DNS name/s for which a certificate is requested", of course).

Comment: Care to comment on the need for 1 SSL certificate that covers both domain and additional subdomains?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Yes I understand I need a Wild SSL Certificate, I have a SSL Certificate for oso-wonen.nl but we do voluntary work and no money. To pay €79,95 extra (Wild SSL Certificate) for only a subdomain, so I thought there was an easy way to do it.

Please can you give me instruction how to get the free SSL certification for this subdomain.

Thanks in advance for your help.

With kind regards,

Wim.

Comment: Yes I understand I need a Wild SSL Certificate, I have a SSL Certificate for oso-wonen.nl but we do voluntary work and no money. To pay €79,95 extra (Wild SSL Certificate) for only a subdomain, so I thought there was an easy way to do it. Please can you give me instruction how to get the free SSL certification for this subdomain.

Comment: You don't need a wildcard certificate; a wildcard certificate would be `*.oso-wonen.nl` and would accept *any* subdomain name, but you only need a certificate with two Subject Alternate Names: `www.oso-wonen.nl` and `bestuur.oso-wonen.nl`; if you also want to use `oso-wonen.nl` (without `www`), that would make three SANs total. No need for a wildcard certificate at all.